# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/train.tsv'

Tags: python, file-not-found

I'm trying to run a .ipynb file from a gitlab repo on jupyternotebook. I got the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/train.tsv'` so I figured that python is looking for the .tsv file in the wrong directory so in order to solve this I have to find where the .tsv file is first, but I can't find the file anywhere in the repo. Not sure if I'm understanding this error correctly.

[Here is the full traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ6AR.png)

Comment: Try using `os.getcwd()` to see your current work directory (or `os.listdir()`).

Comment: I just tried it and all i got was the ">" symbol. Doesn't this mean it needs more input? I tried typing in the file I'm looking for but got a syntax error.

Comment: Maybe the file wasn't committed to the repo. Have you found the desired file in the repo?

Comment: I've been searching for an answer to the same question but my mistake is porbably badly defined and made paths. Anyway you may find this thread useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22282760/filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: @NikolajKiel I couldn't find it in the repo but I think it's just not there and I have to downlaod it separately

Comment: @JoannaKastelik Thanks, I'm still trying to work around this problem but that thread is informative