# Open files within same directory

Tags: python, file

I tried opening a file and it says, `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'words.txt'` although it is in the same directory, here is the code I am using:

```
words = []

with open("words.txt", "r") as file:
    words_string = file.read()
    words = words_string.split()
```

Comment: try `os.listdir(<directory_path>)` (i.e. list all elements in the directory) to check whether `words.txt` is actually in there.

Comment: @JayPeerachai I don't really know what the path is

Comment: I checked in Terminal (I'm on Mac) and it says that it's there

Comment: just run `os.listdir()` in your script.

Comment: Just make sure, your working directory (the directory displayed in cmd/terminal) is same as where the file is, where you run your script.

Comment: Doesn't print anything

Comment: Nevermind, it says it's in there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FileNotFoundError: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22282760/filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.listdir()` to list the files in the current working directory and check if the desired file is present.
To print the path of current working directory use `os.getcwd()`.
I would recommend to use absolute paths instead of relative path to make the code clean and less prone to errors. If you don't want to use the absolute paths then use `os.chdir(directory_name)` to change the current working directory during runtime.

Comment: Just tried absolute path, doesn't work either, same error

Comment: If you're sure that the file is present, try checking the file permissions

Comment: How do I do that

Comment: Use `ls -l` to list out the files with their permissions and check if you see `-r--r--r--` _r_ in every 3 bits, the signifies that the users, group, others have read permission. Check [this](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/manage-permissions) out for more info

Comment: words.txt has -rw-rw-rw-@

Comment: Then there must be a problem with the path you're providing. Make sure it's correct!

Comment: I'm just trying to use a relative path.