# need to load the file from local drive to Google cloud platfrom cloud storage using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

i am trying to copy the file from local drive to gcp cloud storage using python code as written below but I am getting the below file not found error.

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'C:/Users//vithal//test.csv'

'''

```
from google.cloud import storage
import os
#pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage.
def upload_to_bucket(landing_bucket_name):
  storage_client = storage.Client()
  project_id = 'abc'
  dataset_id = 'xyz'
  landing_bucket_name = '123'
  landing_blob_name = 'test_upload'
  local_path = "C://Users//test.csv"


#print(buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())

  bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(landing_bucket_name)  

  blob = bucket.blob(landing_blob_name)
  blob.upload_from_filename(local_path)


#returns a public url
  return blob.public_url
```

'''

Comment: Have you referred to this links: http://net-informations.com/python/err/path.htm and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22282760/filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is a file there? It's a very strange place to store a file!

I'd expect the path to be more like `c:/Users/vithaln/test.csv`

Comment: thanks Mesh, just for example i have given like that, but the path is like that only. please suggest

Comment: @vithaln - since the error is about the source file, show the actual source file details in your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley the source file is nornal csv file only , but the python code written in gcp is not reading the file and not even the path. Please suggest